# How to use conditions in react JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list where is coming `0 and 1` Now I want to toggle it if I click on 1 it will be convert to 0 and if I click on 0 it will be convert to 1.

Demo:- https://codesandbox.io/s/ternary-condition-qlqpmj?file=/src/App.js

My Code:-

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    title: "title1",
    IsActive: 1
  },
  {
    title: "title2",
    IsActive: 0
  },
  {
    title: "title3",
    IsActive: 1
  },
  {
    title: "title4",
    IsActive: 1
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [data2, setData2] = useState(data);
  const [updatedToggle, setUpdatedToggle] = useState();

  const deleteHandle = (title, toggle) => {
    console.log({ title, toggle });
    if (toggle === "1") {
      setUpdatedToggle("0");
    } else {
      setUpdatedToggle("1");
    }
    console.log(updatedToggle);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data2
        ? data2.map((val, i) => (
            <div className="box" key={i}>
              <h2>{val.title}</h2>
              <Button onClick={() => deleteHandle(val.title, val.IsActive)}>
                Delete
              </Button>
              <Button>{val.IsActive}</Button>
            </div>
          ))
        : ""}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: what is your problem? do you want to toggle `isActive` *of the element which was clicked*?

Comment: yes I want to toggle which was clicked

Comment: Usually you'd create a subcomponent for each element of data.  That subcomponent has its own "updatedToggle" type state var.  That way each element of data gets its own place to remember if the toggle is on or off for that particular element.

Comment: @James I just need to toggle if i clicked on 1 it should be 0 and if i clicked on 0 it should be 1

Comment: Yeah, but each element of data has to track that separately.

Comment: yes @james this is already working separately if you will click on 1 you will get the separate value in console.

Comment: @RohitVerma Please note as you're using strict comparison (===) and assigning numbers for `IsActive` then condition `toggle === "1"` will always give you a false, because it's type will not match. strict comparison (===) will only return true when types & values are both the same & equal.

Answer (score 0):

This code has some of "bad code", but it will be wokrking for you.

*Using `title` as a key - not good practice.

*Using `i` for finding needed object - not good practice.

For this goal you need to have unique `id`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    title: "title1",
    IsActive: 1
  },
  {
    title: "title2",
    IsActive: 0
  },
  {
    title: "title3",
    IsActive: 1
  },
  {
    title: "title4",
    IsActive: 1
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [data2, setData2] = useState(data);
  
  const deleteHandle = (index) => {
    let { IsActive } = data2[index]

    IsActive = IsActive === 0 ? 1 : 0

    // Copy data
    const newData2 = [...data2]

    newData2[index] = { ...newData2[index], IsActive }

    setData2(newData2)
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data2
        ? data2.map((val, i) => (
            <div className="box" key={val.title}>
              <h2>{val.title}</h2>
              <Button onClick={() => deleteHandle(i)}>
                Delete
              </Button>
              <Button>{val.IsActive}</Button>
            </div>
          ))
        : ""}
    </div>
  );
}
```